# Bootstrap 4 Beta - Is Popper.js required?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, popper.js

i wanted to ask if Popper.js is absolutely necessary or not if i don't use dropdown menus.
Are there any other parts driven by popper that would not work without the library?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you search for "popper" in [Bootstrap 4's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/), the following results will come up:

> Tooltips rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning.
>
> Popovers rely on the 3rd party library Popper.js for positioning.
>
> Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection.

So these are the Bootstrap 4 components that need Popper.js.

Though Popper.js is stated as required for Bootstrap 4, and Bootstrap 4 JS logs an error if it can't find Popper, **you can still use Bootstrap 4 JS without Popper, if you don't need tooltips, popovers, dropdowns, nor modals.**

For example navbar's JS functionality (mobile menu on the right) works well:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your answer suits my expectations.
Unfortunately modals won't work without popper.

Comment: Oh, it seems that the documentation is not complete enough. I add it to my answer (it may be useful in the future).

Comment: Something must have been changed, I can use dialogs without popper, but I'm surprised that bootstrap can figure out where to open dropdown in navbar without popper but not any other places

Answer (score 17):

Popper.js is not required if you use **bootstrap.bundle.js** or **bootstrap.bundle.min.js** instead of **bootstrap.js** or **bootstrap.min.js**.  That's because the bootstrap.bundle.* libraries contain popper internally.
You can download all the bootstrap files from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/download/)

Comment: In bootstrap 4.3.1 bootstrap.bundle.js is bigger than bootstrap.js and I'm pretty sure it includes popper so is pretty much the contrary :(

Answer (score 9):

Not anymore, check [THIS](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24984) issue It seems Bootstrap has bundled Popper and Bootstrap v4 into a bundle.min.js file that is available if you try downloading now.  [HERE](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js) is a link directly to the bundled min file. Hope that helps someone who is not interested in adding a separate popper file

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, if you only use the non-Popper JS functionality of bootstrap, you can fake Popper and load bootstrap (thus Bootstrap will work and won't throw an error about Popper being missing):

```
<script>
    window.Popper = {}
</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: with bootstrap 4.1.x it is more like `var Popper  =function(){}`

Answer (score 2):

Popper.js is required IF you're using Bootstrap JS. It's *not* required if you're using only the Bootstrap CSS.

[Read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start)